Поле label при подключении Юмани
Подключил Юмани. Теперь нужно при оплате отправлять по Email информацию из формы, которую заполняет заказчик перед оплатой. В письме приходит вся информация, кроме той которая написана в <input name="label">. Вроде бы все как по видеоролику и в соответствии с документацией. Месяц уже работаю только над этой задачей, перестал что-либо понимать. Сразу прошу прощения за ужасно костыльный код, пока учусь.
<div id="pay-form">
        <a class="popap-close" href="#close"></a>
        <form id="formYoo" method="POST" action="https://yoomoney.ru/quickpay/confirm">
            <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="****************"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="quickpay-form" value="button"/>
            <input id="names" type="hidden" name="names">
            <div>
                <input id="telYoo" name="tel" type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required>
                <p class="gray">После оплаты с вами свяжется менеджер по указанному вами телефону</p>
                <input id="nameYoo" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown__button">Выбрать компанию доставки</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown__list">
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio">СДЭК</label>
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio">КИТ</label>
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio">Экспресс Авто</label>
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio">ТК Энергия</label>
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio">ПЭК</label>
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio">Деловые Линии</label>
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio">Байкал Сервис</label>
                            <label class="dropdown__list-item" onclick="document.querySelector('#other-input').value = '';"><input name="radio-dropdown" type="radio" id="other-checkbox">Другой</label>
                        </ul>
                        <input type="text" name="select-category" value="" class="dropdown__input-hidden" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="other-input" placeholder="Введите компанию доставки">
                <p class="gray">Введите удобный адрес пункта выдачи выбранной транспортной компании или ваш адрес для доставки курьером:</p>
                <input id="adrYoo" name="adr" type="text" placeholder="Адрес" required>
                <p class="gray">Cтоимость доставки уточняйте в выбранной компании</p>
                <textarea id="textarea-pay" placeholder="Ваш комментарий"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="successURL" value="https://test.ru/">
            <input id="label" type="hidden" name="label" value="нет информации о покупателе">
            <input id="sum-prise" type="hidden" name="sum" value="" data-type="number"/>
            <a href="#" onclick="YooMany();" class="button button-pay">Перевести</a>
        </form>
</div>
<script>
        sumYoo = document.querySelector("#sum-prise");
        telYoo = document.querySelector("#telYoo");
        nameYoo = document.querySelector("#nameYoo");
        productYoo = document.querySelector("#names");
        adrYoo = document.querySelector("#adrYoo");
        textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea-pay");
        label = document.querySelector("#label");
        
        
        function YooMany() {
            localStorage.setItem('YooMany_sumYoo', sumYoo.value);
            localStorage.setItem('YooMany_telYoo', telYoo.value);
            localStorage.setItem('YooMany_nameYoo', nameYoo.value);
            localStorage.setItem('YooMany_textareaYoo', textarea.value);
            localStorage.setItem('YooMany_productYoo', productYoo.value);
            if (document.querySelector("#other-input").value != "") {
                localStorage.setItem('YooMany_dropdownYoo', document.querySelector("#other-input").value);
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('YooMany_dropdownYoo', document.querySelector(".dropdown__button").innerHTML);
            }
            localStorage.setItem('YooMany_adrYoo', adrYoo.value);
            label.value = 'Имя: ' + localStorage.getItem('YooMany_nameYoo') + ';     ' + 'Телефон: ' + localStorage.getItem('YooMany_telYoo') + ';     ' + 'Заказ: ' + localStorage.getItem('YooMany_productYoo') + '     ' + 'Сообщение: ' + localStorage.getItem('YooMany_textareaYoo');
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')).forEach((ident) => {
                localStorage.removeItem("name-product" + ident);
                localStorage.removeItem("image-product" + ident);
                localStorage.removeItem("type" + ident);
                localStorage.removeItem("prise" + ident);
                localStorage.removeItem("mini-desc" + ident);
                localStorage.removeItem("description" + ident);
                localStorage.removeItem("number" + ident);
                localStorage.removeItem("ident" + ident);
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')).forEach(() => {
                    let remove = removeFrom(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')), ident);
                    localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(remove));
                });
            });
            document.querySelector('#formYoo').submit();
        }
    </script>

Вместо домена вписал "test.ru" и вместо номера кошелька "****************" в целях безопасности. В реальном коде там стоят реальный домен и реальный кошелек)

Так у вас 2 input с name=label и 1 input с id=label. Вы отбираете значение второго input с id=label

Этого косяка я впритык не увидел, спасибо, что о нём сказали, но к сожалению когда исправил проблема осталась

Обновите в вопросе код. Как и что вы исправили. И самое главное, добавьте в вопрос - какое поведение и что вы ожидаете? Т.е. что и где должно появится/отправится и т.д.

Правки в коде внёс, на счёт точной задачи: Пользователь заполняет форму где указывает своё имя, адрес доставки, телефон и компанию, которой доставляется товар, также в <input id="names"> содержится наименование всех товаров, которые он добавил в корзину согласно документации если я эти все данные отправлю через <input name="label">, то они должны прийти как описание оплаты, но эти данные не приходят, хотя данные точно находятся в <input name="label">, так как если поставить ему type="text", то все данные в этом поле отображаются, то есть данные есть, но отправится не могут. Cпасибо)

Есть подозрение, что форма отправляется быстрее, чем заполняется поле. Попробуйте повесить обработчик события по другому и в самом начале функции вызвать event.preventDefault() - как сделать, можно подсмотреть тут

Если форма отправлялась быстрее чем заполняется поле, то по идее отправилось бы "нет информации о покупателе", которое у меня прописано в value
